# Marklogic mlreloadmodule is throwing error after adding ml unit tests

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

While running mlrelaodmodules i am getting below error

```
> Execution failed for task ':mlLoadModules'.
> > Local message: failed to apply resource at documents: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES:
> xdmp:document-insert("/test/css/coverage.css",
> document{text{"/**&#10;* Copyright 2012-2019 MarkLogic
> Corporation&#10;*&#10;..."}}, <options
> xmlns="xdmp:document-insert"><permissions><sec:permission
> .../>...</permissions></options>) -- Conflicting updates
> xdmp:document-insert("/test/css/coverage.css",
> document{text{"/**&#10;* Copyright 2012-2019 MarkLogic
> Corporation&#10;*&#10;..."}}, (<sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>10509128414665615137</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>13041542794130379697</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>insert</sec:capability><sec:role-id>15520654661378671735</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>insert</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>10509128414665615137</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>update</sec:capability><sec:role-id>15520654661378671735</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>7089338530631756591</sec:role-id></sec:permission>),
> (), 0) and xdmp:document-insert("/test/css/coverage.css",
> document{text{"/**&#10;* Copyright 2012-2019 MarkLogic
> Corporation&#10;*&#10;..."}}, (<sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>10509128414665615137</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>insert</sec:capability><sec:role-id>15520654661378671735</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>13041542794130379697</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>execute</sec:capability><sec:role-id>10509128414665615137</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>insert</sec:capability><sec:role-id>12062832703728382323</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>update</sec:capability><sec:role-id>15520654661378671735</sec:role-id></sec:permission>,
> <sec:permission
> xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"><sec:capability>read</sec:capability><sec:role-id>7089338530631756591</sec:role-id></sec:permission>),
> (), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the task with this property.

`mlModulesLoaderBatchSize=1`

If it's taking more time to load then try increasing the value.

Below document can help you more in debugging the problem.

[Debug module loading](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Debugging-module-loading)

Comment: Do i need to add it in gradle.properties

Comment: You can add in properties file or pass in command as `-PmlModulesLoaderBatchSize=1`